# How do I remove msysgit's right click menu options?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, msysgit

This isn't the best programming question but lets face it, the server fault guys aren't well versed in git, so I think its more towards this audience.

I want to switch to TortoiseGit, or PortableGit in my shell, but I'm left with these annoying context-menu options.

How do I get them to go away? Do I have to write a script to uninstall them?

Comment: A deleted answer from the OP [referenced this URL](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/) as containing a solution.

Answer (score 623, accepted):

### 64-Bit Windows

From a cmd.exe window, run these commands:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah"
regsvr32 /u git_shell_ext64.dll
```

### 32-Bit Windows

From a cmd.exe window, run these commands

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah"
regsvr32 /u git_shell_ext.dll
```

### Windows 10

If you are on Windows 10 and the previous methods did not work try to uninstall the application and reinstall it. But be careful during the installation process **unchecking Windows explorer integration**

[image]

Comment: File is git_shell_ext64.dll for a 64bit OS like Windows 7 tends to be

Comment: For newer versions of GitExtentions, [follow the instructions here](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1821)

Comment: Thanks for the side note, @TheScrumMeister, although, any reader of that should also remember that GitExtensions is not git-cheetah.

Comment: Also, shall I see if the fix worked instantly, shall I restart the process (e.g., Total Commander) or shall I restart the whole system? Thx for the clarification in advance!

Comment: I don't have these DLL files: git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0

Comment: I just need single menu listed as GIT>> which expands to give child menu that are currently in my right-click handler.. how can i do this ??

Comment: I can't find any .dll files with "shell" in the name under my Git-folder. However, removing the value from regedit did work for me.

Answer (score 96):

Only this registry removal - nothing else - worked for me on Win8.1, as of recent versions:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\git_shell]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\git_shell]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\git_shell]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_shell]
```

Comment: On one strange case on win 7, also this was the only solution that worked.

Comment: This worked great for me on Windows 7, thank you @dfkt!

Comment: Works in Win 10.

Comment: I installed Git using Chocolatey, so a silent install occurred and enabled the shell extensions by default. This was the solution for me. Note: I could only find Reg keys for "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\*"; the others did not appear to exist.

Comment: On win10 (and maybe others) you do not need to reboot or re-login for changes to reflect

Comment: First four lines did the job. THX.

Comment: Works on Windows 11.

Answer (score 40):

You can also disable single entries using CCleaner.

[image]

Comment: Even after disabling the context menu options in ccleaner, the context menu options are still there for me...

Comment: @hexicle for me it worked after restarting the `explorer.exe` process

Comment: Please note that CCleaner used to have a backdoor, for me, that's a big nope lasting forever

Answer (score 20):

When you install msysgit there is an option for "Windows Explorer Integration" that you uncheck to not have them show up.

You can rerun the setup and uncheck the option, or uninstall and reinstall and uncheck it then.

Comment: What would you like, a marquee tag?

Comment: unfortunately that wasn't an option when it was installed, so I think I'm out of luck on it.

Comment: I know it's an option on the latest version, 1.7.0.2-preview20100309. 
It should be the 4th setup screen, right after choosing the installation directory.

Comment: @hasen Hardly the same. He will probably update msysgit at some point so why hack around the registry with changes you will probably forget about?

Comment: @Alex: no need to manually hack registry, I'm pretty sure there are tools that can do that for you.

Comment: @hasen But now you have to install another program. Why not just update? What if that registry change has some unintended consequence down the line that screws with something important?  I think we are beating a dead horse. 

Potato potahto, we are getting the same thing done. I prefer my way.

Comment: Without uninstalling, unchecking the option gives you a warning about NOT uninstalling the option in v 1.8.0, FYI. This is 2 years after the answer so no downvote because it may not have been that way then.

Comment: @CADbloke It however worked for me (removing the context menu entry) despite the warning.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows 10 nothing of the above did work for me. The best solution I found is to uninstall the application and reinstall it and be careful during the installation process to uncheck **Windows explorer integration**

[image: remove git remove click menu options]

Comment: I can confirm that the accepted answer works on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: +1 This was the only thing that worked for me on one of my Windows 10 machines.  That said, the accepted answer worked on another.

Comment: Same here (Win10 x64). Have to uninstall it and install again.

Comment: This is also what worked for me. (Win10 x64). Had to uninstall it and install again.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and All the above answer does not work for me, THEN Finally I found a solution in below steps.

**Step 1 :** Type `regedit` in start menu

**Step 2 :** Run the registry editor

**Step 3 :** Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell`

**Step 4 :** click on "shell"

**Step 5 :** Right click on "Git Bash Here" and choose the delete option

Cheers

Comment: This worked for me. Most probably because my git is installed for the user, rather than system-wide.

Answer (score 4):

On **Windows 10 64 bits** you need to do both of the following:

**1. Delete registry entries**

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\git_gui

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\git_shell

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\git_gui

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\git_shell

For convenience or if you want to automate removal (for example to use after choco upgrade) you can run in Powershell (run as Admin):

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT | Out-Null
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Directory\shell\git_gui" -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Directory\shell\git_shell" -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Directory\Background\shell\git_gui" -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Directory\Background\shell\git_shell" -Recurse
```

**2. Unregister the shell extensions dll** to remove additional menu entries (GitExt clone..., GitExt Create New Repository, etc.):

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\GitExtensionsShellEx64.dll"
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to what dfkt said, there's one more location that has it, for the Library Folders:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2901758233-4091616725-3820123586-1012\Software\Classes\LibraryFolder\background\shell\git_gui
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2901758233-4091616725-3820123586-1012\Software\Classes\LibraryFolder\background\shell\git_shell
```

That specific number between HKEY_USERS and Software probably varies from person to person, and account to account, so make sure it's right for you.

So, the modified, complete registry removal would be:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\git_shell]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\git_shell]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\git_shell]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_shell]

[-HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2901758233-4091616725-3820123586-1012\Software\Classes\LibraryFolder\background\shell\git_gui]

[-HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2901758233-4091616725-3820123586-1012\Software\Classes\LibraryFolder\background\shell\git_shell]
```